# Analytic (or just qualitative) solution to *any* nontrivial electrodynamic dynamic problem?

Tags: electromagnetism

I just realized that, after a basic course in electrodynamics, I have no idea whatsoever how to solve the most trivial non-static example in an "exact" way. By this, I mean the following:
I know (at least in theory) how to calculate fields when I assume a certain (time dependent) charge distribution, or how to calculate some aspects of motion (e.g., forced vibration) when I assume certain fields; but I do not know how to calculate the fields *and* the motion in any nontrivial example.

The most basic example seems to be:

**Two particles of identical charge and mass move in a non-parallel way.** (Or, if parallel, then not on the same line; I just want to have the example at least "twodimensional")

E.g., at $t=0$,  $P_1$ is at $(1,0,0)$ with speed $(-1,0,0)$ and $P_2$ is at $(0,1,0)$ with speed $(0,-1,0)$.

(Remark: This seems to be the standard example to demonstrate that from a "mechanical" (non-field) point of view, electrodynamics does not preserve total momentum or angular momentum; you have to take into account the momentum in the field as well.)

Is there an analytic solution for this problem? Or a reasonable approximation? Or a qualitative analysis? I would love to see how, over time, energy, momentum and angular momentum is distributed amongst the particles and the field. (Of course I am more than happy to neglect gravitation (i.e., spacetime should be flat)).

Edit:

- I just realize that, even given a simple and beautiful analytic solution, the hope of seeing the "distribution" of Energy between particles and field seems to be a bit naive, given the fact that (if I remember correctly) point charges lead to infinite energy (in the field).
- As pointed out in the comments, an analytic solution seems unlikely. Apart from numeric methods: is there a nice qualitative analysis of the situation?

Comment: Generically, there are no closed-form solutions to three-body problems except in special cases. You have two bodies plus a field, and a field acts like infinitely many degrees of freedom. Therefore it would be *very* surprising if there were a closed-form solution.

Comment: Does *"a basic course in electrodynamics"* mean undergrad? Did you have a separate math-methods course (or equivalently cover a lot of methods in PDEs as you went along)? A more advanced math background will generally let you do good approximations to more problems, but as @BenCrowell says exact solutions are few and far between.

Comment: I hope that most people do not consider this a trivial problem.  If I were to look at Maxwell's Equations for example given the scenario outlined -- they're all involved in their full complexity -- that is both E and B fields due to the moving charges.  I was imagining how I might setup the problem and thought one method would be to consider just the fields produced by one particle all by itself.  Then, bring in the other particle and its motion as a perturbation to the first scenario of the single particle.

Comment: @K7PEH: *I hope that most people do not consider this a trivial problem.* On the contrary, it's almost certainly an impossible problem.

Comment: @BenCrowell -- Good, those impossible problems I leave for others to think about.